# Insufficient permission when running 'adb shell'

Tags: android

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. And I need to use  'adb shell' to connect to my device on linux:

I get Insufficient permission when running 'adb shell'as myself.
But when I run it as 'root', it works.

How can I fix 'adb shell' so that I don' need to run it as root everytime?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the problem and solution are the same as in question "[adb devices command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510284/adb-devices-command-not-working)".

In short: you must inform Ubuntu that android device, connected to USB can be used by unprivileged users (that's forbidden by default).

That's even decribed in official **Android Developer's Guide**: [Configuring USB Access](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#configuring-usb-access), but I prefer a bit simplier [51-android.rules](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkio3jk2u552sdt/51-android.rules) file.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try changing the owner of the file adb ?

```
 sudo chown <usergroup>.<username> adb
```

This is may work for you!

Comment: 'adb' is under my user name and group.  I think the permission thing comes up when it needs USB connection or something.