# Debug Android Wear app on ASUS ZenWatch 2 using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, adb, wear-os, android-debug

I'm trying to enable USB debug on my ASUS ZenWatch 2. What I've done so far:

1. Opened `Settings -> About` and tapped on the `Build Number` 7 times. Now I'm developer.
2. Opened `Developer Settings` and tapped on `Enable ADB debug`.

Typed `adb devices` in console and here's what I see:

```
artem@home-pc:~/Downloads$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
0926d8da031f9091    device
????????????    no permissions
```

First device is my already enabled Nexus 5, second is the ASUS ZenWatch 2.

Okay, I remember that on [Linux](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/device.html#VendorIds) machines I also need to add a new entry to my `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` so the system can detect my device. Now, my `51-android.rules` file looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Again, first line is for phone, second is for watches.

Nothing changes, `adb` still does not recognize my device.

Am I missing something? Does ASUS ZenWatch 2 support USB debug at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb devices command not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510284/adb-devices-command-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're noob like me, don't forget to reboot the PC after you've changed the `udev` rules.

If you want to go the hard way, reload udev as described in one of those articles: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82470/what-is-the-correct-way-to-restart-udev), [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/497436/can-udev-be-restarted-without-a-reboot).