# Android : adb shell, no command adb found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb

I am simply trying to run the adb shell so I can kill a process for testing purposes. I am in the directory platform-tools and the adb executable is in there. When I try to run the shell it says adb command not found. I am running eclipse (through Ubuntu) and using an emulator. Not sure whats going on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if the problem is "file not  found" message -  see :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517493/adb-command-not-found-in-linux-environment/13419991#13419991

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run it like that `./adb shell` (note the `./`)

By default, local folder is not in the path.

Comment: thank you.I wasted a good bit of time on that. I appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

adb is not in your path.  It's easy enough to add it to your path though, if you're using the latest version of the sdk, open up your .profile file (in your home directory, that's (dot) profile) and add the lines:

```
PATH=/path/to/sdk/android-sdk-linux_86/tools:$PATH
PATH=/path/to/sdk/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link for adb like this : ln -s adb /usr/local/sbin/adb
then you can run adb anywhere