# adb devices command shows nothing

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

At the moment I'm busy with the Android SDK. I got it working, but when I entered `$sudo adb` shell. It gave `sudo: adb: command not found`. For this problem I checked this link: [adb devices command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510284/adb-devices-command-not-working) But if I enter $sudo adb devices now. Noting happens.

Not even *daemon not running. starting it now op port 5037 * and the rest. But it looks like this:

```
    michiel@ubuntu: ~$ sudo adb devices
    michiel@ubuntu: ~$
```

So I can enter the next command. Someone knows how to fix that? It's the same with $sudo adb shell. Nothings comes up.

When I enter adb devices without the sudo. I get the error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/sbin/adb: No such file or directory.
```

#### But it's there!

```
echo $PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/michiel/jdk1.6.0_29/bin:home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

#### Edit

When I start Eclipse now, I get the next error: `Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program"/home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb":java.io.IOException:error=2, No such file or directory.`

### SOLVED

Last weekend I installed a clean install of Ubuntu. I downloaded the `ia32.lib and openjdk` instead of java jdk and install is manually. After some struggling I managed to connect the device and now I can see it. Thx for the help :)

Comment: @Vivek Kalkur How do you mean it's there? You mean its in the PATH. I know, but I dont get *deamon not running. starting now on port 5037 * sudo adb devices just does NOTHING!

Comment: I just edited your question without altering the theme of it.

Comment: @Vivek Kalkur Thank you for the edit :)

Comment: @Michielodc I am already using openjdk, and facing the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I also had this problem two days ago and I searched and searched so I found that my ubuntu is 64-bit and adb is not match to ubuntu 64-bit so I used the below command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

and my problem was solved
don't forget, you should export your java-version-sdk.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following at the end of your .bashrc file (can found in your home directory):

```
export PATH=:/home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Now use the adb command without sudo. This solved the problem for me.

HTH!

Comment: Now it says after adb devices: -bash: /home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory.

Comment: is the path to your android sdk correct? :P Did you also check if you're using the correct binary? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: the PATH I entered is the one you posted. Even tried it twice now.

Comment: i merely copied the path to your sdk from your question. check if it does exist. sometimes the solution may be as trivial as that.

Answer (score 1):

try to kill & start the adb server 
cmd

adb kill-server

adb start-server

Comment: I tried that before. But now it says -bash: /home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory. But I tried that before, even reboot.

Comment: have you did apt-get install ia32-libs
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Comment: I do not have ia32-libs yet, but as far I know you do not need it. But I'll download it when I'm home. Im behind some nasty proxy here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running on the linux platform so for that running binary will be followed by .

```
try with sudo .adb devices
    or try with sudo .adb shell
```

Comment: navigate to the android sdk where you find the adb binary file and try , so we can check whether that is proper or not.

Comment: I entered cd /home/michiel/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools and after that I entered ./adb It said -bash: ./adb: No such file or directory. Im a beginner with this. So I probably did it wrong.

Comment: please go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517493/adb-command-not-found-in-linux-environment

Answer (score -1):

> Check adb is available in your android sdk --> platform-tools. If it
>   available Follow these steps:
>
> Set android vars
>
> Initially go to your home and press `Ctrl + H` it will show you hidden
>   files now look for .bashrc file, open it with any text editor then
>   place the lines below at the end of file:
>
> export ANDROID_HOME=/myPathSdk/android-sdk-linux export
>   PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
>
> Now Reboot the system
>
> It Works!