# React Native 'hello world' quick start: "could not connect to development server"

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to do the react native 'hello world', and I'm using usb debugging on my android.

I ran `react-native run-android`, then `react-native start`.

I can view the js file in `localhost`, but get 'could not connect to development server' message on my phone.

I followed the instructions to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, then realized that command doesn't exist, so I ran `adb forward tcp:8081 tcp:8081` instead.

Still no luck. Using react-native@0.22.0, ubuntu 14.04. My phone is nexus 5 on android 6.0.1.

How can I allow my phone to access my `localhost`?

By the way, it is working over wifi, but I'd like to get it working over usb.

Comment: Going to `localhost` on the device, is the device itself. Did you try using the actual ip address?

Comment: Right, I tried to use the forward command to forward to my pc's localhost (I think that's the way it works). That did not work. Using my ip address, and wifi, did work. I'd like to use usb, however, and can't get that to work.

Comment: Use usb for what exactly? The internet connection doesn't go over usb

Comment: If I interpreted `adb forward` correctly online, it forwards **from the PC** and **to the device**

Comment: OK, good to know. The troubleshooting info seems to give 2 options, one wired, one wireless. 1. If you're on a wired connection, run 'adb reverse ...'. 2. If your device is on the same wifi network, you can put in your computer ip/port. I can do #2, but cannot do #1. How do I do #1, given that 'reverse' is no longer an option for the adb command?

Comment: I have the exact same problem running the Hello World app in the emulator.

Comment: Just for fun, I started from the beginning to try to recreate this. It worked this time. I think because they added this to the docs: "A common issue is that the packager is not started automatically when you run react-native run-android. You can start it manually using:

cd AwesomeProject
react-native start"

Comment: How exactly did you solve the problem?  `adb forward` did not work for me. I am on android 4.3

Comment: Well, like I wrote, the thing that I think fixed it for me was the 'react-native start'.  What's the error you're seeing? I'm also on android 6.

Answer (score 26):

Just another scenario, this error happened to me when I forgot to run `react-native start` command. I usually follow the steps [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) when I start new project. The steps in a nutshell are as follows (Android in my case):

- Start Android Studio -> AVD Manager -> select your aVD and click Start from action
- inside the directory where you want to create your new project, open your command line and run:

  ```
  $ react-native init <Your new project name/it is also the registration name>
  $ cd <the new directory you created>
  $ react-native start  //This is the step that I forgot
  ```
- Open a new command prompt and run the following inside the same directory(you just created) to launch the app on your AVD.

  ```
  $ react-native run-android
  ```
- If everything is set up correctly, you should see your new app running in your Android emulator shortly.
- You'll find in the file index.android.js in the home directory of your project, the last line contians the App registry using the same name you used in the first command above

Comment: The command `react-native start` is completely missing at the official _React Native Getting Started_ guide. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: This solution (two terminals) was the only one that worked for me. Very easy to miss. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` Only works for android 5.0 + for running app on devices with android versions lesser than 5.0 hit following command after `npm start` is done in Terminal (in app directory folder).

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

now run the app, it will work. Only drawback is that every time you make a change you need to fire the command again and run the app again.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution :)

I am on ubuntu 16, so, I used command ip addr show which gave me my computer ip address.

I used this ip address and I was able to access localhost on my mobile.

Finally I added the ip address and port no to devsettings of android phone and My app was able to access development server

Answer (score 2):

10 mins ago I had the same problem I guess, and the way I solved this was reading this

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

and when I did that, I found that I didn't have `android-tools-adb` installed, 
so looking around I found

['No command 'adb' found' error on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532440/no-command-adb-found-error-on-ubuntu)

which gives me the answer

```shell
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

and after all this I set

```shell
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

then everything works fine, now I can see my app in my Android device.

BTW the option I choose from react native docs was the one that says me

"Using adb reverse

Note that this option is available on devices running Android 5.0+ (API 21).
Have your device connected via USB with debugging enabled (see paragraph above on how to enable USB debugging on your device).

```shell
Run adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

You can use Reload JS and other development options with no extra configuration

Comment: Using `adb reverse` worked with my android 5.0+, but I can not run on devices 4.0, what can I do?

Comment: @DouglasJunior adb reverse was introduced in android version 5.0. try this:
1.) run - react native start
2.) then run - curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
3.) wait
4.) run  react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

I am having seen the same issue, and that's all because the android app don't have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I would get this error when trying to get it to run on device. It was working fine on my simulators on my computer.

The problem was when I would do adb devices or react-native run-android I would get "ADB is Not Recognized as an internal or external command".

So my fix was to add the path to adb.exe's parent directory to my Environment Variables and then restart my command prompts. After I did that, adb devices would not throw the "unrecognized internal external blah" and it listed my device. I then ran react-native run-android and on startup no more red screen showing the completely useless error message Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication! :)

So I found ADB was located in my folder:

C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
I am on a Windows 10 system. dell is my user name of the computer.

So I went to System Environemnt Variables then found "Path" then clicked "Edit", then clicked "New" and added in "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools".