# "which adb" command shows the path of adb but "adb devices" says no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, adb, webstorm, react-native

I'm practicing REACT NATIVE on UBUNTU 18.x OS, everything was running smooth, yesterday i updated my React native,react & android gradle versions then i recived some error like server adb & client adb doesn't match, i fixed this issue using some commands now once the new project run fine, but as soon as i rebooted my system & run the project,it thrown the error [image]

then i checked adb

```
+adb
```

output:bash: /usr/bin/adb: No such file or directory

```
+which adb
```

output:/usr/bin/adb

```
+type adb
```

output:adb is hashed (/usr/bin/adb)

```
+adb devices
```

output:bash: /usr/bin/adb: No such file or directory

[image]

please help me to resolve this error!

Comment: ```ls /usr/bin/adb``` What is the output of this command? It seems that somehow that file was deleted. Did you upgrade the system? Remove some packets?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rinUnM26EQbVEf9eZgaLVL822Y3WtuFu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Paste the output here, don't take screenshots. Also, don't retype, you made an error. I asked you for ```ls /usr/bin/adb``` and you executed command ```ls user/bin/adb```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge it can be resolved by increasing the num of max users in **sysctl.conf**
on UBUNTU you can run

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

then press **ctrl+O**
then press **ENTRE**
then take the cursor on the end of file and place this line there

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
```

or simply run this command

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
```

you can also follow this
[no-command-adb-found-error-on-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532440/no-command-adb-found-error-on-ubuntu)